# How to connect to my locally run Ethereum node using RPC endpoint?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, prysm

I have an Ethereum full node running locally on my machine and wish to connect to it via an RPC endpoint. I have the node running with the command `geth --http --http.api eth,net,engine,admin --authrpc.jwtsecret ...`

I would like to connect to an ethereum rpc url using my own node.

Any time I attempt to connect using for example `http://localhost:127.0.0.1:port` my connection is unsuccessful but when I use an online rpc provider it is successful.

I do see online suggestions such as `geth --rpcapi eth,net,web3 --rpccorsdomain * --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0` however rpc flags don't seem to work for me..

Answer (score 1):

`--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0` binds all IP addresses on your computer, including `localhost` or (`127.0.0.1`)

The RPC runs by default in a port 8545.

Thus, your default HTTP endpoint where you can connect for JSON-RPC should be `http://localhost:8545`.